# What if we want to output all results and not only distinct results in SQL union?

Tags: sql

Currently

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

outputs only distinct. What if I want to output all results?

Comment: Use `union all` instead of `union`.

Comment: I was going to seggest insertin all union into a temp able... Thanks @Gordon Linoff! [here is a refernce](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_union.asp)

Comment: The SQL standard is a bit strange (sometimes). `UNION [DISTINCT]` is the default, if you want all rows do `UNION ALL`. On the other hand, `SELECT [ALL]` is the default, and if you want top remove duplicates you need do `SELECT DISTINCT`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `UNION ALL` in place of `UNION`, it does not remove duplicate rows and will display all results, like you are looking for.